# Runtime error when using std::bind

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013, stdbind

The following code compiles and runs successfully on OS X using Xcode 6.3.2. However, it crashes when run on Windows using VS2013.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

void validate(const std::string& name, 
              int value, 
              std::vector<std::string>& values)
{
    std::cout << "name: " << name << " value: " << value << "\n";
}

struct Property
{
public:
    Property(const std::string& name,
             const std::function<void(const std::string&, int)>& validationFunction) :
        m_name(name),
        m_validationFunction(validationFunction)
    {
    }

    const std::string m_name;
    const std::function<void(const std::string&, int)> m_validationFunction;
};


const std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Property>> properties
{
    {
        std::make_shared<Property>("identifier1",
        [](const std::string& name, int value)
        {
            validate(name, value, std::vector<std::string>{"foo"});
        })
    },

    {
        std::make_shared<Property>("identifier2",
                                   std::bind(validate,
                                             std::placeholders::_1,
                                             std::placeholders::_2,
                                             std::vector<std::string>{"bar"}))
    }
};


int main()
{
    properties[0]->m_validationFunction(properties[0]->m_name, 4);
    properties[1]->m_validationFunction(properties[1]->m_name, 5);

    return 0;
}
```

The reason for the crash is that the first element in `properties` appears to be corrupt. When I inspect the memory I see this:

```
properties  { size=2 }  std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Property>,std::allocator<std::shared_ptr<Property> > >
[size]  2   int
[capacity]  2   int
[0] shared_ptr {m_name=<Error reading characters of string.> m_validationFunction={...} } [4277075694 strong refs, 4277075693 weak refs] [{_Uses=4277075694 _Weaks=4277075694 }]    std::shared_ptr<Property>
[1] shared_ptr {m_name="identifier2" m_validationFunction=bind(0x011315a5 {schema-init.exe!validate(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,int,class std::vector<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,class std::allocator<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > > > &)}, (_1, _2, { size=1 })) } [1 strong ref] [make_shared]    std::shared_ptr<Property>
[Raw View]  0x0115295c {schema-init.exe!std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Property>,std::allocator<std::shared_ptr<Property> > > properties} {...}    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Property>,std::allocator<std::shared_ptr<Property> > > *
```

If I replace `std::bind` with a direct call to `validate` as for the first element in `properties` then the code executes successfully.

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I've compiled your code using VC2013, but I can't reproduce the error. Also I can't find a mistake when reading your code. Is this really the exact code you were running?

Comment: g++ and clang++ will report an error with `validate` - third argument must be const. Did the compiler report such error? If this issue is fixed, everything works as expected.

Comment: @PaulR. This is exactly the code I ran.

Comment: @karastojko Yes, the compiler reports the error OS X when the 3rd argument is not const. I dropped the const  when running it on Windows but it makes no difference either way - it still crashes.

Comment: Also tried running it with gcc and it works - http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d2636eb3c67a6b2c

Comment: It also runs OK using VS2015.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with this code. This is likely to be a compiler bug.

Answer (score 0):

I noted Paul R's comment above that he successfully ran the code using VC2013 so I updated my copy of Visual Studio 2013 (update 5) and the code now runs ok. So I guess it *was* a compiler bug.